# skimage coordinate system: Confusion about row, column ordering

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have been confusing myself more and more with the skimage coordinate system. So when I load an image with skimage, the images are loaded with the shape (rows, columns) where rows are running from top to the bottom of the image and columns are running from left to right.

Now, I am trying to estimate a projective transformation between set of image keypoints and if I understand correctly, the points have to be supplied in the more conventional (x, y) format where x is columns and y is rows. If so, I need to permute the points. However, I am getting sometimes plausible and sometimes fairly rubbish results using both conventions and would like to know which one to use.

ultimately, the transformation that should be returned with ransac would be used to warp an image using the skimage.transform.warp function.

[UPDATE]: With some code.

Here is the usage, I am confused with:

```
from skimage.transform import ProjectiveTransform
from skimage.measure import ransac
from skimage.feature import plot_matches
from skimage.feature import match_descriptors

# target, source are 2-d images.
# Compute SIFT is done outside skimage but returns c, r indexes.
k_1, d_1 = compute_sift(target)  # c, r indexing
k_2, d_2 = compute_sift(source)

# Match SIFT features and descriptors
matches = match_descriptors(d_1, d_2)

# This is all still c, r indexing
fp = k_1[[[0], [1]], matches[:, 0]] # This is shape (2, n)
tp = k_2[[[0], [1]], matches[:, 1]] # This is shape (2, n)

model_estimate, inliers = ransac((tp.T, fp.T), ProjectiveTransform,
                           min_samples=4, residual_threshold=10,
                           max_trials=100)
```

So, the input to RANSAC is in the form (c, r). Since, this is using the transform object internally, I am guessing this is correct. At the moment, I get mixed result with both (c, r) and (r, c), so I would like to eliminate the uncertainty here and verify I am doing the right thing.

If I may also clarify one more thing. skimage uses the nomenclature (src, dst) and if I use the estimate() method on any transform object, is it true that the returned transformation T has the relationship :

```
T * src_coords = dst_coords
```

I am using version 0.10.1 of skimage.

Comment: All code in scikit-image *except for the transformations module* use the ``(row, col)`` convention.  The transformations module is written that way because it is the convention most often described in papers.  Please see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html#coordinate-conventions  Please include a code snippet showing where you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added some code. My confusion is with the use in RANSAC method which uses the transform models internally.

Comment: As a general rule if you're getting rubbish ever, you're getting rubbish all the time. Just sometimes the rubbish looks OK. Can you give a code example that gives *plausible* results and one that gives *rubbish*? It'll make it easier to debug.

Comment: The code above will give ok or not ok result... If you change to fp = k_1[[[1], [0]], matches[:, 0]] 
tp = k_2[[[1], [0]], matches[:, 1]], it can do the same. I know something else can and probably be wrong but I just want to verify that I have not misunderstood the coordinate system. The other issues are another story.

Comment: Please provide an example source and target image that fails

Comment: I have solved this problem. The problem was not the usage wrt to the coordinate system but the number of RANSAC iterations. In images where a lot of false matches can be generated (due to noise or disambiguity within the features), many more RANSAC iterations were needed to weed out the right subset of correspondences.